# Difference between <f:event listener="#{}" type="postValidate" /> and normal jsf command button

Tags: jsf-2

Good morning, i just want to know the difference between validating JSF components like that:

```
<h:form id="register">

    <h:message for="RegisterGroupPanel" style="color:red;" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="RegisterGroupPanel">

        <f:event listener="#{user.validatePassword}" type="postValidate" /> // diff between that and normal <h:command>

        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username : " />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter username" />
        <h:message for="username" style="color: red;" />


        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter password" />
        <h:message for="password" style="color: red;" />


        <h:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="Confirm password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter confirm password" />
        <h:message for="confirmPassword" style="color: red;" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton action="thanks" value="register" />

</h:form>
```

here i placed the action inside the button and removed the `<f:event listener="#{user.validatePassword}" type="postValidate" />`

```
<h:form id="register">

    <h:message for="RegisterGroupPanel" style="color:red;" />

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="RegisterGroupPanel">


        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username : " />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter username" />
        <h:message for="username" style="color: red;" />


        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter password" />
        <h:message for="password" style="color: red;" />


        <h:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="Confirm password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter confirm password" />
        <h:message for="confirmPassword" style="color: red;" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton action="#{user.validatePassword}" value="register" />

</h:form>
```

what extra functionality does this  `<f:event>`add ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:event>` offers a way to invoke the given `listener` method when an event of the given `type` occurs. The `postValidate` event is invoked by end of validations phase, after the whole form has been processed, converted and validated, but **before** the model has been updated. So if you intend to perform the job based on submitted values, you'd need to grab them via `UIInput#getValue()`.

The command button's action method is invoked during invoke application phase, after the update model values phase. So if you need the submitted values, you can just access the bean properties directly.

Note that none of both approaches offer a nice way to automatically display the message at the desired components, nor that the `FacesContext#validationFailed()` would return `true` in case of validation failure.

From the two ways, The `<f:event type="postValidate">` way is technically the most correct way to perform the job, if the listener method is properly implemented. Validation ought to be performed during validations phase and not during invoke application phase.

However, a better way would be to use a component which is specialized for the very purpose of validating multiple fields on equality. The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has such a component: the [`<o:validateEqual>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual). In your particular case, you could use it as follows:

```
<h:form id="register">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="RegisterGroupPanel">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username : " />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter username" />
        <h:message for="username" style="color: red;" />

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter password" />
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:message for="password" style="color: red;" />
            <h:message for="validateConfirm" style="color:red;" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="Confirm password : " />
        <h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please enter confirm password" />
        <h:message for="confirmPassword" style="color: red;" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <o:validateEqual id="validateConfirm" components="password confirmPassword" message="Passwords are not equal" />    
    <h:commandButton action="thanks" value="register" />
</h:form>
```

Without any custom listener method.